# Regex / Vim: Matching everything except a pattern, where pattern is multi-line?

Tags: regex, vim

Is there a way in Vim to perform a similar operation to

```
:v/PATTERN/d
```

where PATTERN is a *multi-line regex pattern*? I'm sure there is a way to do this in script, but I am mainly curious as to if it is possible to do using only standard regex substitution or Vim commands, because at this point it is more academic than an actual need.

My example is the following:

```
asdf

begin
   blah
end

asdf

alsdfjasf

begin
   random stuff
end
...
```

I want to get the blocks of begin/end with the lines between them, but ignore everything outside of the blocks, ultimately ending up with

```
begin
   blah
end

begin
   random stuff
end
...
```

My thoughts were to do

```
:v/begin\_.\{-}end/d
```

where everything didn't match that would be deleted or even copied to register, but obviously :v and :g only work on single lines.

Then, I started going down the path of running a substitute and substitute everything with empty string that DIDN'T match the `begin\_.\{-}end` pattern, but I cannot grasp how to achieve such using look-behinds or anything. The regex works perfectly fine when just searching, but I can't figure out how to tell the regex engine to find everything BUT that pattern. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### clear reg `a`

```
qaq
```

#### append `begin...end` to reg `a`

```
:g/begin/,/end/y A
```

#### open new tab

```
:tabnew
```

#### put reg `a`

```
"ap
```

Comment: Brilliant and absolutely fast response. It amazes me how long you can use Vim and learn new stuff every day.

Comment: @kev can we skip the first step? by using:  `y a` instead of `y A`

Comment: @LovesProbability Specify them as lowercase
letters to replace their previous contents or as uppercase letters to append
to their previous contents.

Answer (score 4):

Flip it inside out, and delete everything delimited by the pattern:

```
:%s/\%(^end\n*\|\%^\)\zs\_.\{-}\ze\%(^begin\|\%$\)//
```

- `\%( ... )` - non capturing group
- `^end\n*` - the end of your pattern
- `\%^` - the beginning of the file
- `\zs` - don't include anything matched before this point in the string to be replaced
- `\_.\{-}` - non-greedy matching of anything (including newlines)
- `\ze` - don't include anything matched after this point in the string to be replaced
- `^begin` - the beginning of your pattern
- `\%$` - the end of your pattern

Comment: Awesome! I want to mark this as an answer, but I already marked the first response (from kev) as an answer, and I will feel bad removing it. Technically they both answer my question, but this one I think answers the original question I had about replacing :v/pattern/d.

Answer (score 0):

The commands executed by g and v can themselves take ranges, so you can act on everything from "begin" to "end" with `:g /begin/ .,/end/xxx` where xxx is a command to execute on that range.  You cant really use this for `:v` but there are several ways you could do it in multiple passes, e.g.

```
"mark all the lines we want to keep by putting '@' at the start of the line"
:g/^begin/ .,/^end/  s/^/@/
"delete all unmarked lines"
:v/^@/ d
"remove the markers"
:s/^@//
```

Of course this assumes you do not have any lines in the file starting with @.

Alternatively you could delete everything between each "end" and the next "begin"

```
:g/^end/ +1,/^begin/-1 d
```

then delete the cruft left at the start and end of the file:

```
:1,/^begin/-1 d
:$?^end?+1,$ d
```

Note the use of `$?^end?+1` to search backwards from the end of the file to find the last line starting with "end".

N.B. the last two will delete too much if the file starts with "begin" or ends with "end" at that point, so check before you use them.