# Match Methods with References to Global Variables

Tags: regex, vbscript, non-greedy

This question is heavily related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573708/vbscript-regex-match-everything-except-multi-line-pattern), but it has to do with grabbing methods that contain references to global variables (not commented out).

I'm using the following regular expression and test string to check to see if it works, but it's only partially working:

**Regular Expression**

```
^((?:(?:Public|Private)\s+)?(?:Function|Sub).+)[\s\S]+?(GLOBAL_VARIABLE_1)[\s\S]+?End\s+(?:Function|Sub)$
```

(I need part of the regular expression this way with the capturing group so that I can grab the name of the method as a sub-match).

**Test String**

```
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'
'   the code:   Header
'
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Dim GLOBAL_VARIABLE_1
Dim GLOBAL_VARIABLE_2
Dim GLOBAL_VARIABLE_3

Public Function doThis(byVal xml)
'' Created               : dd/mm/yyyy
'' Return                : string
'' Param            : xml- an xml blob

     return = replace(xml, "><", ">" & vbLf & "<")

     GLOBAL_VARIABLE_1 = 2 + 2

     doThis = return

End Function


msgbox GLOBAL_VARIABLE_1



Public Function doThat(byVal xPath)
'' Created               : dd/mm/yyyy
'' Return                : array
' 'Param            : xPath

     return = split(mid(xPath, 2), "/")

     GLOBAL_VARIABLE_2 = 2 + 2


     doThat = return

End Function


GLOBAL_VARIABLE_2 = 2 + 2


Public Sub butDontDoThis()
'' Created               : dd/mm/yyyy
'' Return                : string
' 'Param            : obj

     For i = 0 To 5
          return = return & "bye" & " "

     Next

End Sub


GLOBAL_VARIABLE_3 = 3 + 3


Public Sub alsoDoThis(byRef obj)
'' Created               : dd/mm/yyyy
'' Return                : string
' 'Param            : obj, an xml document object

     For i = 0 To 4
          return = return & "hi" & " "

     Next

     GLOBAL_VARIABLE_1 = 1 + 1

End Sub


GLOBAL_VARIABLE_3 = 3 + 3
```

Using http://www.regexpal.com/, I'm able to highlight the first method that references a global variable. However, the regular expression is not doing what I expect it to do with the other methods. The regular expression is also picking up other methods that don't have references to a specific global variable, and it ends with the last method that is actually using the global variable. I've determined the problem to be that the `[\s\S]+?(GLOBAL_VARIABLE_1)[\s\S]+?End\s+(?:Function|Sub)$` part is doing a minimal / non-greedy match so that it keeps looking until it finds an actual match.

In summary the expression should follow these rules:

- to stop scanning the method it is currently checking when it sees the **first** end of a method's declaration. In this example, only the `doThis` and `alsoDoThis` methods should be matched for `GLOBAL_VARIABLE_1`, but I'm not sure what the regular expression should be.
- The regular expression should also only match methods that are actually using global variables
- If a `GLOBAL_VARIABLE_1` is commented out, then it is really not being used by the method. A commented `GLOBAL_VARIABLE_1` should not trigger a positive match for the method.

Comment: Your desired solution of having a single regex would not be easily accomplished and would create a difficult to maintain expression. Also a complex expression like that would probably run slower then simply wrapping logic around two separate regular expressions. This is one of the reasons that regex is not a solution for parsing strings like HTML. If you're really interested in having a single expression, then suggest submitting this with a bounty which requires you to have 250 points on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Description

I'd do this in two steps, first identify each of your functions and subs. Here I'm using a reference `\1` to ensure we're matching the correct end function or end sub. This regex also grabs the function name and places that into group 2. This can then be used later if part 2 is correct

`(?:Public|Private)\s+(Function|Sub)\s+([a-z0-9]*).*?End\s+\1`
[image]

Then test each of these to see if they contain your variable, note in this test I'm using multiline matching to ensure the comment character does not appear before `Global_Variable` on the same line. This also checks that the `GLOBAL_VARIABLE_1` is not preceded by any of the following

- alphanumeric with or without a `_` seperater. This would need to be updated with all the characters you might find in a variable name. Including a hyphen `-` here might be confused with a minus sign used in an equation.
- comment character `'`

`^[^']*?(?![a-z0-9][_]?|['])\bGLOBAL_VARIABLE_1`

[image]

## VB Part 1

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Module Module1
  Sub Main()
    Dim sourcestring as String = "replace with your source string"
    Dim re As Regex = New Regex("(?:Public|Private)\s+(Function|Sub)\s+([a-z0-9]*).*?End\s+\1",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase OR RegexOptions.Singleline)
    Dim mc as MatchCollection = re.Matches(sourcestring)
    Dim mIdx as Integer = 0
    For each m as Match in mc
      For groupIdx As Integer = 0 To m.Groups.Count - 1
        Console.WriteLine("[{0}][{1}] = {2}", mIdx, re.GetGroupNames(groupIdx), m.Groups(groupIdx).Value)
      Next
      mIdx=mIdx+1
    Next
  End Sub
End Module

$matches Array:
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Public Function doThis(byVal xml)
'' Created               : dd/mm/yyyy
'' Return                : string
'' Param            : xml- an xml blob

     return = replace(xml, "><", ">" & vbLf & "<")

     GLOBAL_VARIABLE_1 = 2 + 2

     doThis = return

End Function
            [1] => Public Function doThat(byVal xPath)
'' Created               : dd/mm/yyyy
'' Return                : array
' 'Param            : xPath

     return = split(mid(xPath, 2), "/")

     GLOBAL_VARIABLE_2 = 2 + 2


     doThat = return

End Function
            [2] => Public Sub butDontDoThis()
'' Created               : dd/mm/yyyy
'' Return                : string
' 'Param            : obj

     For i = 0 To 5
          return = return & "bye" & " "

     Next

End Sub
            [3] => Public Sub alsoDoThis(byRef obj)
'' Created               : dd/mm/yyyy
'' Return                : string
' 'Param            : obj, an xml document object

     For i = 0 To 4
          return = return & "hi" & " "

     Next

     GLOBAL_VARIABLE_1 = 1 + 1

End Sub
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Function
            [1] => Function
            [2] => Sub
            [3] => Sub
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => doThis
            [1] => doThat
            [2] => butDontDoThis
            [3] => alsoDoThis
        )

)
```

## VB Part 2

Found in this text

```
Public Function doThis(byVal xml)
'' Created               : dd/mm/yyyy
'' Return                : string
'' Param            : xml- an xml blob

     return = replace(xml, "><", ">" & vbLf & "<")

     GLOBAL_VARIABLE_1 = 2 + 2

     doThis = return

End Function
```

example

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Module Module1
  Sub Main()
    Dim sourcestring as String = "replace with your source string"
    Dim re As Regex = New Regex("^[^']*?GLOBAL_VARIABLE_1",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase OR RegexOptions.Multiline)
    Dim mc as MatchCollection = re.Matches(sourcestring)
    Dim mIdx as Integer = 0
    For each m as Match in mc
      For groupIdx As Integer = 0 To m.Groups.Count - 1
        Console.WriteLine("[{0}][{1}] = {2}", mIdx, re.GetGroupNames(groupIdx), m.Groups(groupIdx).Value)
      Next
      mIdx=mIdx+1
    Next
  End Sub
End Module

$matches Array:
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  Param            : xml- an xml blob

     return = replace(xml, "><", ">" & vbLf & "<")

     GLOBAL_VARIABLE_1
        )

)
```

---

not found in this text

```
Public Function doThis(byVal xml)
'' Created               : dd/mm/yyyy
'' Return                : string
'' Param            : xml- an xml blob

     return = replace(xml, "><", ">" & vbLf & "<")

  '   GLOBAL_VARIABLE_1 = 2 + 2

     doThis = return

End Function
```

example

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Module Module1
  Sub Main()
    Dim sourcestring as String = "replace with your source string"
    Dim re As Regex = New Regex("^[^']*?GLOBAL_VARIABLE_1",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase OR RegexOptions.Multiline)
    Dim mc as MatchCollection = re.Matches(sourcestring)
    Dim mIdx as Integer = 0
    For each m as Match in mc
      For groupIdx As Integer = 0 To m.Groups.Count - 1
        Console.WriteLine("[{0}][{1}] = {2}", mIdx, re.GetGroupNames(groupIdx), m.Groups(groupIdx).Value)
      Next
      mIdx=mIdx+1
    Next
  End Sub
End Module

Matches Found:
NO MATCHES.
```

---

also not found in this text

```
Public Sub butDontDoThis()
'' Created               : dd/mm/yyyy
'' Return                : string
' 'Param            : obj

     For i = 0 To 5
          return = return & "bye" & " "

     Next

End Sub
```

example

```
   Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
    Module Module1
      Sub Main()
        Dim sourcestring as String = "Public Sub butDontDoThis()
    '' Created               : dd/mm/yyyy
     '' Return                : string
     ' 'Param            : obj

     For i = 0 To 5
          return = return & ""bye"" & "" ""

     Next

End Sub"
        Dim re As Regex = New Regex("^[^']*?GLOBAL_VARIABLE_1",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase OR RegexOptions.Multiline)
        Dim mc as MatchCollection = re.Matches(sourcestring)
        Dim mIdx as Integer = 0
        For each m as Match in mc
          For groupIdx As Integer = 0 To m.Groups.Count - 1
            Console.WriteLine("[{0}][{1}] = {2}", mIdx, re.GetGroupNames(groupIdx), m.Groups(groupIdx).Value)
          Next
          mIdx=mIdx+1
        Next
      End Sub
    End Module

    Matches Found:
    NO MATCHES.
```

## Disclaimer

There are a lot of edge cases which can trip this up, for example if you have a comment with `'  end function` or have a if you assign a string value to a variable like `thisstring = "end sub"`

Yes I realize OP was for VBscript, I've included these examples to demonstrate the overall logic and that the regular expressions work.

Comment: The question is about VBScript, not about VB.

Comment: I'm using VB to show the overall logic and that the regular expressions work as described.

Comment: @Denomales This is a little helpful, but I'm looking for a way to optimize gathering the names of method that contain references to global variables. I've gone from scanning line-by-line (which takes a horrendously long time) to scanning blocks of methods as one string. I think that it would be much faster if I were to have a regular expression that returns just the names of methods that contain references to global variables.

Comment: I changed the part 1 regex to also capture the function/sub name so you can iterate over all the matches from part 1, and providing part 2's test passes then you can easily pull the name from part 1's array.

Comment: There is an issue with the second regular expression in that similarly named global variables (but not exactly the same) still match so long as the name ends with the string I'm looking for. For instance, the regex `^[^']*?GLOBAL_VARIABLE_1` would also find the global variable `ABCD_GLOBAL_VARIABLE_1`, but I just want it to match just `GLOBAL_VARIABLE_1` so long as it is not commented out.

Comment: I was able to fix this by using the following regular expression: `^[^']*?\bGLOBAL_VARIABLE_1\b`. The `\b` right before and after the global variable name ensures that there are no additional letters before and after the global variable name.

Comment: Updated solution to cover several edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

Found the culprit. The issue is caused by the highlighted part of your regular expression:

```
((?:(?:Public|Private)\s+)?(?:Function|Sub).+)[\s\S]+?(GLOBAL_VARIABLE_1)[\s\S]+?End\s+(?:Function|Sub)
```

`[\s\S]+?` is a non-greedy match, but that does not necessarily mean it's the shortest match. Simplified example:

```
Public Function doThis(byVal xml)
  GLOBAL_VARIABLE_1
End Function

Public Function doThat(byVal xPath)
  GLOBAL_VARIABLE_2
End Function

Public Sub butDontDoThis()
  GLOBAL_VARIABLE_3
End Sub

Public Sub alsoDoThis(byRef obj)
  GLOBAL_VARIABLE_1
End Sub
```

When the regular expression is applied to the sample text, it first matches the first function (groups marked as bold text):

```
Public Function doThis(byVal xml)
  GLOBAL_VARIABLE_1
End Function
```

However, after that match, the first part of the expression (`((?:(?:Public|Private)\s+)?(?:Function|Sub).+)`) matches the next function definition (`Public Function doThat(byVal xPath)`), and `[\s\S]+?(GLOBAL_VARIABLE_1)` then matches *all* text until the *next occurrence* of `GLOBAL_VARIABLE_1`:

```
Public Function doThat(byVal xPath)
  GLOBAL_VARIABLE_2
End Function

Public Sub butDontDoThis()
  GLOBAL_VARIABLE_3
End Sub

Public Sub alsoDoThis(byRef obj)
  GLOBAL_VARIABLE_1
End Sub
```

There is no implicit "don't include `End Function`" in `[\s\S]+?`.

The simplest solution to your problem may be a combination of regular expression and string match:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
text = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\Temp\sample.txt").ReadAll

Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "((?:(?:Public|Private)\s+)(Function|Sub).+)([\s\S]+?)End\s+\2"
re.Global  = True
re.IgnoreCase = True

For Each m In re.Execute(text)
  If InStr(m.SubMatches(2), "GLOBAL_VARIABLE_1") > 0 Then
    WScript.Echo m.SubMatches(0)
  End If
Next
```

It extracts the body of each procedure/function (`SubMatches(2)`) and then checks with `InStr()` if the body contains `GLOBAL_VARIABLE_1`.

Comment: I already use the `Global` property in the `RegExp` object to `True`, and I still get the same results.

Comment: Did you remove `^` and `$` from the expression?

Comment: That page checks *JavaScript* regular expressions, not *VBScript* regular expressions. I ran your expression (with my suggested modifications) against your test string in VBScript, and it produces the desired 2 (sub)matches.

Comment: This still does not help; it's grabbing all methods that don't have a global variable, and the last in the set of matches do. I only want the methods that contain the global variable I'm looking for.

Comment: The 2 (sub)matches I'm looking for in this example are `Public Function doThis(byVal xml)` and `Public Sub alsoDoThis(byRef obj)`, since these methods refer to `GLOBAL_VARIABLE_1`. However, the current regular expression I'm using (`^((?:(?:Public|Private)\s+)(?:Function|Sub).+)[\s\S]+?(GLOBAL_VARIABLE_1)[\s\S]+?End\s+(?:Function|Sub)$`) is including the other methods in the second match. This is because the non-greedy regex is eventually extending beyond the first `End (Sub|Function)` it sees for the current function to any other text that has `GLOBAL_VARIABLE_1` and then `End (Sub|Function)`

Comment: This is what I eventually went about doing, except I used a regular expression check instead of an InStr check to avoid commented code, as @Denomales posted. Just wish there was a regular expression that would avoid having to do these multiple checks to run through the code quicker. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

## Description

This regex will break up the text into strings where each string contains a single function or sub. It will also validate the that the string has **a non-commented `GLOBAL_VARIABLE_1`** by looking for the first line of code inside the function which doesn't have a `'` preceding the desired `GLOBAL_VARIABLE_1` value. The expression will also handle `'` as regular characters if they are embedded in a double quoted string like `variable = "sometext ' more text" + GLOBAL_VARIABLE_1`

`(?:Public|Private)\s+(Function|Sub)\s+([a-z0-9]*)(?:(?!^End\s+\1\s+(?:$|\Z)).)*^(?:[^'\r\n]|"[^"\r\n]*")*GLOBAL_VARIABLE_1.*?^End\s\1\b`

[image]

## Groups

Group 0 will contain the entire matched function/sub

1. will contain `function` or `sub` accordingly
2. will contain the name of the function/sub

## Examples

Input text

```
Public Function ValidEdgeCase1(byRef obj)
  SomeVariable = "some text with an embedded ' single quote" + GLOBAL_VARIABLE_1
End Sub

Public Sub SkipEdgeCase(byRef obj)
  SomeVariable = "some text with an embedded ' single quote" ' + GLOBAL_VARIABLE_1
End Sub

Public Function FailCommented(byVal xml)
'  GLOBAL_VARIABLE_1
End Function

Public Function FAilWrongName1(byVal xPath)
  GLOBAL_VARIABLE_2
End Function

Public Sub FAilWrongName1()
  GLOBAL_VARIABLE_3
End Sub

Public Sub alsoDoThis(byRef obj)
  GLOBAL_VARIABLE_1
End Sub

Public Sub IHeartKitten(byRef obj)
  GLOBAL_VARIABLE_1
End Sub

Public Sub IHeartKitten2(byRef obj)
  GLOBAL_VARIABLE_1
End Sub

Public Function FailCommented(byVal xml)
'  GLOBAL_VARIABLE_1
End Function
```

Sample Code

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Module Module1
  Sub Main()
    Dim sourcestring as String = "replace with your source string"
    Dim re As Regex = New Regex("(?:Public|Private)\s+(Function|Sub)\s+([a-z0-9]*)(?:(?!^End\s+\1\s+(?:$|\Z)).)*^(?:[^'\r\n]|"[^"\r\n]*")*GLOBAL_VARIABLE_1.*?^End\s\1\b",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase OR RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace OR RegexOptions.Multiline OR RegexOptions.Singleline)
    Dim mc as MatchCollection = re.Matches(sourcestring)
    Dim mIdx as Integer = 0
    For each m as Match in mc
      For groupIdx As Integer = 0 To m.Groups.Count - 1
        Console.WriteLine("[{0}][{1}] = {2}", mIdx, re.GetGroupNames(groupIdx), m.Groups(groupIdx).Value)
      Next
      mIdx=mIdx+1
    Next
  End Sub
End Module
```

$matches Array:

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Public Function ValidEdgeCase1(byRef obj)
  SomeVariable = "some text with an embedded ' single quote" + GLOBAL_VARIABLE_1
End Sub
            [1] => Public Sub alsoDoThis(byRef obj)
  GLOBAL_VARIABLE_1
End Sub
            [2] => Public Sub IHeartKitten(byRef obj)
  GLOBAL_VARIABLE_1
End Sub
            [3] => Public Sub IHeartKitten2(byRef obj)
  GLOBAL_VARIABLE_1
End Sub
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Function
            [1] => Sub
            [2] => Sub
            [3] => Sub
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => ValidEdgeCase1
            [1] => alsoDoThis
            [2] => IHeartKitten
            [3] => IHeartKitten2
        )

)
```

Comment: This issue has been bugging me for awhile, sorry for the late reply.